# SilverStripe HTMLEditorField front-end

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I have a site I've just updated to SS3.2 using the Multiform module. Everything is working great except that my HTMLEditorFields are now just textareas on the front-end forms. I've read that in order to use HTMLEditorField outside of the CMS the HTMLEditor_Toolbar is required as per the documentation: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/forms/field_types/htmleditorfield/#using-the-editor-outside-of-the-cms

However, I am using the multiform module and not sure how to integrate the two. Does anybody have any ideas?

Also setting the number of rows does not appear to work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Pete

Code example:

```
<?php

class Gap extends DataObject{

    static $db = array(
        'NotesOnGaps' => 'HTMLText',
    );

    static $has_one = array(
        'CallEvent' => 'CallEvent'
    );

    public function getFrontendFields($params = null){
    $fields = $this->scaffoldFormFields(array(
        'restrictFields' => array(
            'NotesOnGaps',
        ),
        'fieldClasses' => array(
            'NotesOnGaps' => 'HTMLEditorField',
            )
        )
    );

    $fields->push( new HTMLEditorField("NotesOnGaps", "Notes on gaps"));

    return $fields;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You add the "NotesOnGaps" field twice, once through scaffoldFormFields() (where the fieldClass is not needed, cause HTMLText scaffolds automatically to HTMLEditorfield), one time manually...
Do you really need TinyMCE or could another editor field be ok? There are some on packagist afaik.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.

Yeah the idea is to have a tinymce instance on the front-end. Also to be able to control the height of the textarea

Comment: @wmk do you know of a way to set parameters on htmleditorfield through fieldclasses array?

Comment: a good ressource is https://github.com/jonom/silverstripe-tinytidy. Did you get HTMLEditor working in frontend? if yes it would be great if you could answer your question.

Comment: hi @wmk, thanks for the link. Unfortunately HTMLEditorField WYSIWYG  still not appearing, not sure how to integrate the HTMLEditor_Toolbar which apparently is what I need for it to work outside of the cms. Would love to know the correct syntax when using with scaffoldFormFields https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/forms/field_types/htmleditorfield/#using-the-editor-outside-of-the-cms